# How do I get first unused ID in the table?

Tags: sql, mysql

I have to write a query wherein i need to allocate a `ID` (unique key) for a particular record which is not being used / is not being generated / does not exist in database.

In short, I need to generate an `id` for a particular record and show it on print screen.

E. g.:

```
ID  Name

1   abc
2   def
5   ghi
```

So, the thing is that it should return `ID=3` as the next immediate which is not being generated yet, and after this generation of the `id`, I will store this data back to database table.

It's not an HW: I am doing a project, and I have a requirement where I need to write this query, so I need some help to achieve this.

So please guide me how to make this query, or how to achieve this.

Thanks.

I am not able to add comments,, so thats why i am writing my comments here..
I am using MySQL as the database..

My steps would be like this:-

1)  Retrieve the id from the database table which is not being used..

2)  As their are no. of users (website based project), so i want no concurrency to happen,, so if one ID is generated to one user, then it should lock the database, until the same user recieves the id and store the record for that id.. After that, the other user can retrieve the ID whichever is not existing.. (Major requirement)..

How can i achive all these things in MySQL,, Also i suppose Quassnoi's answer will be worth,, but its not working in MySQL.. so plz explain the bit about the query as it is new to me.. and will this query work in MySQL..

Comment: What RDBMS are you using for your project?

Comment: Be careful with concurrency, here.  If you have multiple users, the time gap between running Quassnoi's query and storing the results in the DB may result in duplicate IDs.  Why not just let the RDBMS manage your ID columns?

Comment: As DDaviesBrackett writes, if this is not homework, then it suffers from a serious real world problem: Two processes may run the query, and get their answer, and then each try to insert a duplicate record. If this is just to answer the question: Are there any gaps? that is different. It is then just funny that anyone would care.

Comment: This question worries me, it appears as though you are missing some database fundamentals. I say this because DDaviesBrackett is right (barring some incredible exception) that the RDBMS should manage your id column.

Comment: DDaviesBrackett raises a ost important issue.  Writing the query is one thing, using the result you get back is another thing.
Real world, you'd not want to go back and re-use an ID that had already been used, or skipped.

Answer (score 7):

I named your table `unused`.

```
SELECT  id
FROM    (
        SELECT  1 AS id
        ) q1
WHERE   NOT EXISTS
        (
        SELECT  1
        FROM    unused
        WHERE   id = 1
        )
UNION ALL
SELECT  *
FROM    (
        SELECT  id + 1
        FROM    unused t
        WHERE   NOT EXISTS
                (
                SELECT  1
                FROM    unused ti
                WHERE   ti.id = t.id + 1
                )
        ORDER BY
                id
        LIMIT 1
        ) q2
ORDER BY
        id
LIMIT 1
```

This query consists of two parts.

The first part:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    (
        SELECT  1 AS id
        ) q
WHERE   NOT EXISTS
        (
        SELECT  1
        FROM    unused
        WHERE   id = 1
        )
```

selects a `1` is there is no entry in the table with this `id`.

The second part:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    (
        SELECT  id + 1
        FROM    unused t
        WHERE   NOT EXISTS
                (
                SELECT  1
                FROM    unused ti
                WHERE   ti.id = t.id + 1
                )
        ORDER BY
                id
        LIMIT 1
        ) q2
```

selects a first `id` in the table for which there is no next `id`.

The resulting query selects the least of these two values.

Comment: will not find ids smaller than the first existing id. Ie. if table has ids 3,4,6 will find 5, but not 1 and 2. You can union with another select that searches for id bigger than 0 and smaller than first id.

Comment: My steps would be like this:-

1) Retrieve the id from the database table which is not being used..

2) As their are no. of users (website based project), so i want no concurrency to happen,, so if one ID is generated to one user, then it should lock the database, until the same user recieves the id and store the record for that id.. After that, the other user can retrieve the ID whichever is not existing.. (Major requirement)..

How can i achive all these things in MySQL

Comment: Your particular query, is not working in MySQL and also i am not able understand what is the query actually doing.. So plz if you can explain a bit of the query..

Comment: This query is also not working sir,,  ----
ERROR 1248 (42000): Every derived table must have its own alias----

This error is coming

Comment: how can i resolve this error.. Also if possible how can i avoid concurrency issues. I am using JDBC java technology,, so i should want that this ID should not be allocated to anyother user.. It should lock the database, or some method to lock through jdbc connection.. Any One, which should be effective..

Answer (score 5):

Depends on what you mean by "next id" and how it's generated.

If you're using a sequence or identity in the database to generate the id, it's possible that the "next id" is not 3 or 4 but 6 in the case you've presented.  You have no way of knowing whether or not there were values with id of 3 or 4 that were subsequently deleted.  Sequences and identities don't necessarily try to reclaim gaps; once they're gone you don't reuse them.

So the right thing to do is to create a sequence or identity column in your database that's automatically incremented when you do an INSERT, then SELECT the generated value.

Comment: This will do,, but since there are different users who will be accessing the database,, there could be a time when two users recieves the same ID,, so how is it possible to avoid this concurrency,, plz also give some example also.. Thanx..

Comment: If you use a auto_increment field in mysql, you don't have to worry about concurrency. Just make user you use LAST_INSERT_ID() after to get the ID of the row you just inserted.

Answer (score 2):

Should work under MySql.

```
SELECT TOP 100
    T1.ID + 1 AS FREE_ID 
FROM TABLE1 T1
LEFT JOIN TABLE2 T2 ON T2.ID = T1.ID + 1
WHERE T2.ID IS NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

```
/*
This is a query script I wrote to illustrate my method, and it was created to solve a Real World problem where we have multiple machines at multiple stores creating transfer transactions in their own databases,
that are then synced to other databases on the store (this happens often, so getting the Nth free entry for the Nth machine should work) where the transferid is the PK and then those are synced daily to a MainFrame where the maximum size of the key (which is the TransactionID and StoreID) is limited.  
*/

--- table variable declarations
/* list of used transaction ids (this is just for testing, it will be the view or table you are reading the transaction ids from when implemented)*/

DECLARE @SampleTransferIDSourceTable TABLE(TransferID INT)     

/* Here we insert the used transaction numbers*/

DECLARE @WorkTable TABLE (WorkTableID INT IDENTITY (1,1), TransferID INT) 

/*this is the same table as above with an extra column to help us identify the blocks of unused row numbers (modifying a table variable is not a good idea)*/

DECLARE @WorkTable2 TABLE (WorkTableID INT , TransferID INT, diff int)  

--- Machine ID declared

DECLARE @MachineID INT

-- MachineID set

SET @MachineID = 5

-- put in some rows with different sized blocks of missing rows.
-- comment out the inserts after two to the bottom to see how it handles no gaps or make 
-- the @MachineID very large to do the same.
-- comment out early rows to test how it handles starting gaps.

INSERT @SampleTransferIDSourceTable ( TransferID ) VALUES ( 1 )
INSERT @SampleTransferIDSourceTable ( TransferID ) VALUES ( 2 )
INSERT @SampleTransferIDSourceTable ( TransferID ) VALUES ( 4 )
INSERT @SampleTransferIDSourceTable ( TransferID ) VALUES ( 5 )
INSERT @SampleTransferIDSourceTable ( TransferID ) VALUES ( 6 )
INSERT @SampleTransferIDSourceTable ( TransferID ) VALUES ( 9 )
INSERT @SampleTransferIDSourceTable ( TransferID ) VALUES ( 10 )
INSERT @SampleTransferIDSourceTable ( TransferID ) VALUES ( 20 )
INSERT @SampleTransferIDSourceTable ( TransferID ) VALUES ( 21 )
INSERT @SampleTransferIDSourceTable ( TransferID ) VALUES ( 24 )
INSERT @SampleTransferIDSourceTable ( TransferID ) VALUES ( 25 )
INSERT @SampleTransferIDSourceTable ( TransferID ) VALUES ( 30 )
INSERT @SampleTransferIDSourceTable ( TransferID ) VALUES ( 31 )
INSERT @SampleTransferIDSourceTable ( TransferID ) VALUES ( 33 )
INSERT @SampleTransferIDSourceTable ( TransferID ) VALUES ( 39 )
INSERT @SampleTransferIDSourceTable ( TransferID ) VALUES ( 40 )
INSERT @SampleTransferIDSourceTable ( TransferID ) VALUES ( 50 )

-- copy the transaction ids into a table with an identiy item.
-- When implemented add where clause before the order by to limit to the local StoreID
-- Zero row added so that it will find gaps before the lowest used row.

INSERT @WorkTable (TransferID)

SELECT 0

INSERT @WorkTable (TransferID)

SELECT TransferID FROM @SampleTransferIDSourceTable ORDER BY TransferID   

-- copy that table to the new table with the diff column 

INSERT @WorkTable2

SELECT WorkTableID,TransferID,TransferID - WorkTableID 

  FROM @WorkTable              

--- gives us the (MachineID)th unused ID or the (MachineID)th id beyond the highest id used.

IF EXISTS (

SELECT Top 1

       GapStart.TransferID  + @MachineID - (GapStart.diff + 1)

  FROM @WorkTable2 GapStart

 INNER JOIN @WorkTable2 GapEnd

    ON GapStart.WorkTableID = GapEnd.WorkTableID - 1

   AND GapStart.diff < GapEnd.diff

   AND gapEnd.diff >= (@MachineID - 1)

 ORDER BY GapStart.TransferID

 )

SELECT Top 1

       GapStart.TransferID  + @MachineID - (GapStart.diff + 1)

  FROM @WorkTable2 GapStart

 INNER JOIN @WorkTable2 GapEnd

    ON GapStart.WorkTableID = GapEnd.WorkTableID - 1

   AND GapStart.diff < GapEnd.diff

   AND gapEnd.diff >= (@MachineID - 1)

 ORDER BY GapStart.TransferID

ELSE 

SELECT MAX(TransferID) + @MachineID FROM @SampleTransferIDSourceTable
```

Answer (score 1):

The correct way is to use an identity column for the primary key. Don't try to look at the rows already inserted, and pick an unused value.  The Id column should hold a number large enough that your application will never run out of valid new (higher) values.

In your description , if you are skipping values that you are trying to use later, then you are probably giving some meaning to the values. Please reconsider. You probably should only use this field as a look up (a reference) value from another table.

Let the database engine assign the next higher value for your ID. If you have more than one process running concurrently, you will need to use LAST_INSERT_ID() function to determine the ID that the database generated for your row. You can use LAST_INSERT_ID() function within the same transaction before you commit.

Second best (but not good!) is to use the max value of the index field plus one. You would have to do a table lock to manage the concurrency issues.

Comment: True, and though the question he's asked might not be the right question for him, it's actually a useful question to have an answer to for some of us (i.e. allocate an unused resource from a limited resource pool, versus allocating a unique number from an unconstrained pool as is the case with primary keys).

Answer (score 0):

are you allowed to have a utility table? if so i would create a table like so:

```
CREATE TABLE number_helper (
    n INT NOT NULL
   ,PRIMARY KEY(n)
);
```

Fill it with all positive 32 bit integers (assuming the id you need to generate is a positive 32 bit integer)

Then you can select like so:

```
SELECT MIN(h.n) as nextID
FROM my_table t
LEFT JOIN number_helper h ON h.n = t.ID
WHERE t.ID IS NULL
```

Haven't actually tested this but it should work.

Comment: obviously this is going to suck performance wise, but its the only relatively easy way (i can think of at the moment) of meeting the specifications set forth in the question, as opposed to just explaining identity columns.